# PyCharm: Python version 2.7 does not support a 'F' prefix (even with Python 3.11)

Tags: python, pycharm, code-inspection

Although I use Python 3.11, still PyCharm shows these warning messages:

> Python version 2.7 does not support a 'F' prefix

and:

> Python version 2.7 does not support variable annotations

### What I tried

I tried to reinstall it but still the same problem.
I checked the interpreter. It is Python 3.11.

OS is Windows 11 and PyCharm in latest version. I am using downgraded versions of pip, but I don't think this is the reason.

### Research

I searched online but can't find the solution online.

### Question

How can I avoid those warnings?

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you paste here the code, because right now I don't see any f events/prefixes or any other names you call them. Did you mean f strings?

Comment: im sorry i found the problem it was in  inspection 3.6 wasn't selected also how do i remove my question

Comment: I don't think you can delete the question once an answer has been posted. Just accept the answer.

Comment: First remove the answer - there is a delete option just below it, at the left, and then do the same for the question. Glad that your problem was solved.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Settings->Editor->Inspections. There in Python->Code compatibility inspections, you should see that Python 3.5's box is ticked in.(just tick the 3.6 as well)

This allows you to choose for which versions of Python your code will be inspected.
this answer is originally by @ESkapp

Comment: sorry its @Eskapps